# How to resolve fatal error in bind_param() when executing update statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, bindparam

I am going to update the user profile details(name, password, contact_no, email).
Please help me check how can I improve the code so that I can update successfully.

Here is DbOperations.php updateUser class:

```
public function updateUser($user_id, $name, $password,$contact_no,$email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE `mydb.User` SET `name` = ?, `password`= ? , `contact_no`= ?,`email` = ? WHERE  `user_id` = ? ;");

        $stmt->bind_param("ssisi", $name, $password, $contact_no, $email, $user_id);

        if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1;

        }else{
            return 2;
            }
    }
```

Here is updateProfile.php

```
<?php
require_once'../includes/DbOperations.php';

    $response =array();
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
            if(isset($_POST['user_id'])and
                isset($_POST['name'])and
                    isset($_POST['password'])and
                        isset($_POST['contact_no'])and
                        isset($_POST['email']))

                {//operate the data further
                    $db = new DbOperations();
                    $result=$db->updateUser(
                                        $_POST['user_id'],
                                        $_POST['name'],
                                        $_POST['password'],
                                        $_POST['contact_no'],
                                        $_POST['email']

                                        );
                    if($result == 1){
                                    $response['error']= false;
                                    $response['message'] = "updated successfully";


                    }elseif($result == 2){
                        $response['error']=true;
                        $response['message'] = "updated failed";
                        }
                    }       
            }else{
                $response['error']=true;
                $response['message'] = "empty fileds";

        }


    echo json_encode($response);
```

And the error message:

```
`<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\includes\DbOperations.php</b> on line
<b>49</b>
<br />`
```

Line 49 is :`$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $password, $contact_no, $email, $user_id);`

And I am using an API developer to POST:

[image: updateProfile-error]

[image: Table Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things, which I noticed

1. There is **semicolon** `;` and **braces** `()` in your SQL, which shouldn't be part of it. And it should be

   ```
   "UPDATE `mydb.User` SET `name` = ?, `password`= ? , `contact_no`= ?,`email` = ? WHERE  `user_id` = ?"
   ```
2. Since, `userid` and `contact_no` is `integer`. Then it should be `"ssisi"` instead of `"sssss"`
3. Also, I would suggest to use `User` instead of `mydb.User`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As for point 2, I change it to 'ssisi' since the contact is int as well. But it gives me the same error.

Comment: @NRZDYZXLUTMD please note, that was my assumption (from screenshot posted), I don't know your table structure.So, are you saying after apply point 1, you are getting same exception ?

Comment: @NRZDYZXLUTMD you haven't applied all my suggestion, there is still semicolon. Also, yes, I think, you should use `ssisi` instead.

Comment: @NRZDYZXLUTMD can you just write `User` instead of `mydb.User` ? Also, you need to make sure latest file are deployed at server. You could also try executing same SQL phpadmin and see, if SQL executes. I can't see any other issue here.

Comment: Oh it works! Thanks so much. I think the table name makes the difference. Thanks again~

Answer (score 0):

An `update` statement's `set` clause doesn't have parentheses around it. Just remove them and you should be fine:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE `mydb.User` SET `name` = ?, `password`= ? , `contact_no`= ?,`email` = ? WHERE  `user_id` = ? ;");
# Parentheses removed ------------------------------^------------------------------------------------------^
```